# Setting State of array

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update an array that I have in state by doing this

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.Ar.length; i++) {    
  this.setState({
        items: this.state.items.concat[data.Ar[i]]
    });
}
```

I have it declared as follows

```
this.state = {
            items: []
        };
```

I'm not getting anything back in `items` and it still has a length of zero after setState. I'm fairly new to React so I'm not sure if there is something I am missing here.

component:

```
class SubmitButton extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        clicked: false,
        items: []
    };
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
}

onSubmit() {

    var ddOption = this.props.dropDownOption;
    var search = this.props.searchTerm.term;
    var url = "http://localhost:52688/api/WebView/true/" + search;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    var xhttp.send();
    var response = xhttp.responseText.split(',');
    var data = JSON.parse(response);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.Ar.length; i++) {
        this.setState({
            items: this.state.items.concat(data.Ar[i])
        });
    }
}

render() {
    if (!this.state.clicked) {
        return (
            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.onSubmit()}>Submit</button>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.onSubmit()}>Submit</button>
                <CardTable items={this.state.items} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

}

export default SubmitButton;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the parentheses.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.Ar.length; i++) {    
  this.setState({
        items: this.state.items.concat(data.Ar[i])
    });
}
```

But this would be a better solution:

```
this.setState({
  items: [...this.state.items, ...data.Ar],
});
```

It's called "Destructuring assignment": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

**Edit:** 
Try to use the fetch API instead of the old XHR. You're doing and async request and I guess the data isn't there when you set the state. I also fixed the syntax errors in your component. I hope it will work, but obviously I couldn't test it.

```
class SubmitButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clicked: false,
      items: []
    };
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const search = this.props.searchTerm.term;
    fetch(`http://localhost:52688/api/WebView/true/${search}`)
      .then(response => {
        const data = JSON.parse(response);
        this.setState({
          items: [...this.state.items, ...data.Ar],
          clicked: true,
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('Something went wrong', err))
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.clicked) {
      return (
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.onSubmit()}>Submit</button>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.onSubmit()}>Submit</button>
        <CardTable items={this.state.items} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SubmitButton;
```

Comment: I just gave it a try both ways and I'm still not getting anything back in items.

Comment: Are you sure the `data.Ar` is not an empty array? Can you please paste the whole component into the question?

Comment: I do know that the data.Ar is not empty as I can see whats in it when stepping thru the Chrome debugger.

Comment: Could you please share with me the whole component? It's pretty hard to figure out what's the problem with your code if I don't even see your code :)

Comment: Added the component code to the post. I know its not the cleanest code as I am still learning my way around.

Comment: For some reason the fetch is having issues returning anything in the body to parse so it is causing an error, however I did use the setState that you provided in my original code and it seems to be working so thank you for that!

I'm going to try to do some digging on how I can get the fetch to work, it could be related to the API which i did not build for this project.

Comment: You are likely not to see this, but I am trying again with the fetch method and I'm getting an error back of `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`. It looks like the response I am getting has no body to it.

Comment: Probably it's not a valid JSON. `console.log` the `data.Ar` or try the code without this line.